# how to use OR in switch case statement for checkbox in android studio

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, android-checkbox

```
 switch (view.getId()) {

     case R.id.fruit_apple:
     case R.id.fruit_orange:

         if (checked) {
             selection.add("Orange");
         } else {
             selection.remove("Orange");
         }
         break;

     case R.id.fruit_grapes:

         if (checked) {
             selection.add("Grapes");
         } else {
             selection.remove("Grapes");
         }
         break;
 }
```

How to prevent the output of the above code for orange value duplicated?  when user checked apple and orange, it will display orange twice.

The sample of output:

[image]

Comment: Maybe add a `break` to the apple case?

Comment: i already try to add break; to the apple, but then if apple are checked, it show nothing.just empty.

Comment: And you specifically want to display orange even if apple is selected? Seems like a case of apples and oranges...

Comment: yes! u got it. is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid orange duplicates in the list you need to apply

```
if (checked) {
         if(!selection.contains("Orange")
             selection.add("Orange");
     } else {
         if(selection.contains("Orange")
             selection.remove("Orange");
     }
```

Same goes for other case statements.

Comment: You are welcome. I feel happy to help new developers on Android.

Answer (score 0):

```
String apple,orange,grapes;
CheckBox check_apple, check_orange, check_grapes; 

check_apple.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v;
            if(checkBox.isChecked()){
            apple = checkBox.getText().toString();
            }
        }
    });

    check_orange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v;
            if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                orange = checkBox.getText().toString();
            }
        }
    });

    check_grapes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v;
            if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                grapes = checkBox.getText().toString();
            }
        }
    });

 btn_done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("Submit Data:  ",apple+orange+grapes);

        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you, but actually, i don't want to show "apple"..i try to show only "orange" even if apple are checked. i want the output to be "orange" when apple and orange are checked.  is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code -

```
 switch (view.getId()) {

     case R.id.fruit_apple:

        if (checked) {
             selection.add("Apple");
         } else {
             selection.remove("Apple");
         }
         break;

     case R.id.fruit_orange:

         if (checked) {
             selection.add("Orange");
         } else {
             selection.remove("Orange");
         }
         break;

     case R.id.fruit_grapes:

         if (checked) {
             selection.add("Grapes");
         } else {
             selection.remove("Grapes");
         }
         break;
 }
```

Comment: thank you, but actually, i don't want to show "apple"..i try to show only "orange" even if apple are checked. i want the output to be "orange" when apple and orange are checked. is it possible?

Comment: It should be possible. Post your button onClickListener.